# How can I acquire the Female Paladin hero of Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

I'm a novice **Hearthstone** player and I have seen that there are currently three collectible heroes to buy: a warrior, a hunter and a mage.

However, when matching random games in *Constructed* play, I have seen players that have another hero that is not in the shop list, a female *Paladin*.

I really love that character, so I investigated and discovered that the way to acquire that Hero is by joining **WOW** game and leveling up a character to level 20 (a paid account is not needed to do it from what I have seen.)

Please now let me ask some questions which are closely related to each other to help me understand this:

1. At this precise time, on **29/June/2016**, am I still able to join **WOW** to acquire the female *Paladin* reward?. (it seems that it had a time limit that ended in *March*, but I'm not sure.)
2. Are there more heroes that are not in the shop list and require special actions to acquire them?. (please, give full hero names or links with further documentation.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You actually receive the Paladin Hero through an ingame 'Feat of Strength' [achievement](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=10657/fledgling-hero-of-warcraft), which should still be accessible - achievements doesn't usually disappear, especially Feat of Strengths, unlike WoW 'events'.
   For what it's worth, I recently leveled with a group of friends, and one of them got it!
2. There's also another Mage hero, Khadgar, which is no longer accessible.
   According to the [Hearthstone gamepedia](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Khadgar), he **MAY** become accessible again in the future, but I haven't personally seen any real source for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry I'm not sure if what you said conflicts with what a community manager said in Hearthstone forums: "anyone who leveled a character to level 20 after 11 a.m. PST on March 11 will be eligible to receive Lady Liadrin.". This means the way to achieve this reward has changed and now is more difficult and needs a PAID account of WoW?. Also, please could you gave the exact name of that achievement?. I'm looking at here: http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Feats_of_Strength_achievements

Comment: The achievement is "Fledgling Hero of Warcraft"  (http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=10657/fledgling-hero-of-warcraft) as linked in my answer!
Also, it should be obtainable on a guest account according to (http://www.wowhead.com/news=251822/lady-liadrin-paladin-hero-free-reward-for-level-20-world-of-warcraft-players), which was posted on the 16th. March

Comment: Confirmed, I reached level 20 with a "starter" WoW account and obtained the Paladin avatar for Hearthstone. Note for interest: From lvl 1 to 15 was really hard, best way is to make quests but it is slow to acchieve so it will take 1 or two days to be on level 15, then when in level 15 use the "Dungeon finder" feature to do classic random dungeons, that way will level up the remaining 5 levels (15 to 20) in less than one hour.

Answer (score 2):

1. Despite the claimed time limit, *Lady Liadrin* seems to be still available as of June 29th.
2. Sadly, yes, there was ***Khadgar***, the **third** *mage*. He was exclusively available for purchase for iOS devices as part of a promotion campaign "Apps for Earth", which persisted from April 14th, 2016 to April 24th. (Although the campaign was available only for iOS, once one bought him, then they could use him on any device linked with the account, even on Android.)

Comment: It's hard to choose an answer when both gave precise and useful info. I just to let you know: thanks for your answer!